# How to import text files to fit this clustering algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, nltk

I have 900 .txt files (all of which are American Presidential speeches) saved to a folder on my U:/ drive. I am looking to run some document clustering, following the example given here: http://brandonrose.org/clustering. In his example, the author uses a given repository from `nltk`. How can I import my text files to run through this algorithm properly?

Ultimately, I am trying to group Presidents by the way they speak, so it would be nice to have five or six clusters of Presidents and lists of which Presidents belong to those clusters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `glob` module to get every filename, and then read their content into strings:

```
import glob

for filename in glob.glob("somefolder/*.txt"):
    with open(filename, 'r') as inputFile:
        filecontent = inputFile.read();
```

From now on, you can use the variables `filename` and `filecontent` to create a list of objects (most probably dictionaries) and then you can follow the tutorial you linked.

Comment: If that's not what you need, let me know and I can refine my answer

Comment: That's what I need, but I have no idea where my data (the actual speeches) went! How can I put these into a dictionary?

Comment: Just kidding. That was actually really easy. I got it.